# How to assign inner shadow to inputs in CSS

Tags: css, firefox, input, shadow

Is there any way for assign inner shadow to textbox in CSS or JS ?

I tested outer shadow for textbox and it's ok.

```
input {
     box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; 
}
```

But when I want to assign inner shadow to textbox it doesn't work in Firefox. It works in Chrome.

```
input {
   box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

How can I do that?

ANSWER

Thanks for everybody.
I found the answer myself now.
I used `-moz-box-shadow` and `-webkit-box-shadow` but didn't work for inputs in Firefox but if I remove `border` of textbox it will assign inner shadow in Firefox.

Like this:

```
style="border:none;"
```

**Screenshot:** (in Firefox)

Input shadow when `appearance: none;` and `-moz-appearance: none;` are used:

[image: input shadow when appearance: none; and -moz-appearance: none;]

Input shadow when just `border: none;` is used:

[image: input shadow when just border: none;]

Comment: yes it doing work in chrome, but i need work in firefox

Comment: It works since firefox 18 without prefix. We are in firefox 41..... You are missing something or you don't tell us everything. It's a mobile device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the default appearance has to be overridden in Firefox for the inset `box-shadow` to work properly.

```css
input {
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-width: 0; /* if you don't want the border */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Harry your code doing work for show inner shadow but appear a glass border like button border around the textbox, thanks again

Comment: @MojtabaSh: Sorry, I couldn't understand what it means. Can you post a screenshot? Also, if you don't need the border we can just set the `border` to none or `border-width` to `0`.

Comment: @MojtabaSh: Ok, I got what you meant by looking at the screenshot provided in question. Setting `border-width: 0` like I have mentioned above or `border: none` like you yourself have done would get rid of the borders. By the way, don't add answer into the question itself. You could either post your own answer and accept it (or) accept one of the already posted answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @harry :)))) just i found answer after i posted my question, well your answer is very good and i will accept that, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you're using firefox add -moz prefix to your box-shadow.

-moz-box-shadow : inset 2px 5px 3px;

But this only works on older firefox browsers since new one 13< don't support -moz prefix.

Comment: thanks, but i used -moz-boz-shadow and don't work too

Comment: Can you create a jfiddle of your example? And give firefox us version that you are using.